# Can Jenkins notify me immediately when a unit or integration test fails?

Tags: jenkins, plugins, jenkins-plugins

I want to try a Jenkins plugin that notifies me immediately when a junit or selenium test fails during a maven build. Not sure if this is possible or how to go about. Are there any existing plugins that I could modify?

Comment: You'd have to be much more clear about what "notifies me" and "immediately" mean.  Jenkins can send email when things fail, but many people don't think of that as "immediately". If you use an instant messaging system in your organization, it should be possible to integrate the service interface for that into your build logic.

Comment: @DavidM.Karr I know Jenkins can send an email when things fail but it waits for the whole build to be done before it does that. The build I have have take more than 30 mins. I want to be notified when a test fails so that I can either cancel it or cancel and retrigger (if it's a flaky test)

Comment: Your build should be configured so that it fails and exits on the first unit test failure. There is no point continuing to build something that fails unit tests.